# Adding text to a RoundButton in QT 5.15

Tags: qt, button

Trying to add text to a round button. Gives the error 'Cannot assign to non-existent property: text'.

```
    RoundButton {
            id: circ1
            text: qsTr("RoundButton")
            anchors.right:          parent.right
            anchors.rightMargin:    1.0 * ScreenTools.defaultFontPixelWidth
            anchors.topMargin:      1.0 * ScreenTools.defaultFontPixelHeight
            anchors.top:            parent.top
            Layout.alignment:       Qt.AlignHCenter
            //radius:                 120
            width:                  60
            height:                 60
            contentItem: Text {
                     text: "Plan"
            }
            //font.pointSize:         ScreenTools.smallFontPointSize * ScreenTools.smallFontPointRatio
}
```

Code works as expected without the text property. It also works for a regular button with the text property. I was under the impression a roundbutton should work identical to a regular button. Any idea where i am going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I wasn't able to recreate your issue. A couple things:

1. You have Layout.alignment and anchors.*** These are incompatible I
   believe
2. The text of roundButton is not used as you have set the
   contentItem to a static Text{} Item rather setting you text within it to
   circ1.text